# Huge data loss in folder on external HDD after moving files into it

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery, external-hdd, data-loss

#### The problem

I've had a few PDF/epub files that I wanted to backup on my external drive that holds all my documents and files.

I used Ctrl + X to move PDF files from my desktop directory of my home folder (ext4 inbuilt SSD) to the documents folder on my external drive. Instead of them appearing in the folder, all but 3 of the files I wanted to move disappeared.
And not only this:

**All previous contents of the destination folder on my backup disk disappeared as well!** It were Gigabytes of data. I'm devastated.

The file manager (Caja, Mate's Nautilus) only shows those 3 files, as does ls.
Something, that is also notable is, that I can rename the 3 remaining files in the destination folder, but I cannot copy anything new into that directory. I created a test file in the directory above and moved it into the folder - it disappeared. I opened a terminal and directly changed into the directory where the data loss happened; I entered `touch test`, but a subsequent `ls` does not show any new file(s) (except those 3 that "survived"). Everything that I move into this directory now gets annihilated.
It almost seems as if it behaved comparable to /dev/null.
I ejected the disk using the file manager, waited until the disk stopped rotating, rebooted the computer, plugged the external HDD back in - still only those three files in the folder. There is also nothing in the .Trash* folders. All other folders still work normally.

#### What I need to know now

Is it possible to recover the lost data? At least the old data that was stored there before - I would be shocked, if data could be lost like that just by copying to a folder. How can I find out whether it's a HW issue, or e.g. a file system corruption, or an issue with Ubuntu? This will determine whether I need to immediately buy a new backup disk and rescue all remaining data, or whether I only need to repair the file system.
What is the recommended course of action?

#### System information

Ubuntu Mate 22.04

uname -a

```
Linux Hauptideal-IP-5-Pro-16 6.2.0-34-generic #34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

df -T

```
...
/dev/sda1      ntfs3 4883735548 2529561504 2354174044   52% /media/hauptideal/HDD2
...
```

Some of the files I wanted to copy had very long filenames, and possibly non-ASCII characters (e.g. umlauts) in them. Maybe there could have been an issue with the files themselves?
Before this incident happened, I had tried to use my backup HDD with a USB hub that I recently bought. There was a noise that repeated that I never heard before when using the disk (not the typical startup 'disks-start-to-rotate-sound'), but rather a periodic snap and the device didn't mount. Then I used a standard USB port on my laptop, and it mounted as usual.

**If you need any more information, please add a comment and I will update the question with the requested information.**

Comment: Can you clarify source an destination? Are you saying the source directory, that originally had the files, is the one that now has the mysterious behavior where no new files can be created? And can you confirm what kind of physical device the source was?

Comment: thanks for pointing out that it was unclear which directory is the affected one. The source directory in my Ubuntu installation (ext4 inbuilt SSD) works fine. It is the directory on the external HDD that has issues.

Comment: Did the disk usage of the NTFS disk change to reflect only the three new files? Or is it higher than that and possibly could include the other files as well? Did any of the missing files have colons, quotes, asterisks in the name?

Comment: This is just a guess. Your external HDD may not be mounted, or was unmounted during moving files. The 3 files were copied/moved to the empty mount point `/media/hauptideal/HDD2`. Open the app disks and verify the external HDD is mounted.

Comment: For critical data storage, use a file system that is fully supported in linux. nfts is proprietary, ubuntu can read and write it well, but it can not fundamentally solve possible inconsistencies in the file system. Connect that drive to MS Windows, and have it checked and repaired there. This may restore the old entries, or perhaps even reveal the added files. In principle, though, you should make a mirror copy of the drive first before attempting anything, but that is practically not an easy one.

Comment: @muru there were only few new files. I couldn't tell how much of the HDD got used/freed after the operation, because it's size is in the TBs.

Comment: @user68186 but as soon as it would be mounted correctly, the old files at least should have reappeared, right?

Comment: @vanadium why would it be hard to mirror the disk? Can't I just buy a new HDD and use ddrescue?

Comment: Yes, you can. I find this hard but if you are up to this, this is the safest approach. Prefer to do that before anything else. If an attempt for data recovery fails, then you always can restore the original disk image.

Comment: indeed once the drive is mounted correctly, you should be able to see the old files.

Comment: You note that you've rebooted at least once by now. What's the state of the external drive now? When you say "All other folders still work normally." do you mean on the external drive ? If the drive continues to show  problematic filesystem behavior after reboot, the filesystem or the drive is likely corrupted.

Comment: @ckhan Yes, the affected folder of the drive continues to behave like /dev/null. Something is corrupted. But what? And how to fix it and rescue the data?

Comment: Have you tried running `fsck` over the external drive's filesystem? Follow a tutorial like this: https://linuxhandbook.com/fsck-command. Run it in check mode first, before apply possible fixes.

Comment: @ckhan not yet! Thanks for the idea, I'll check it out. I fear I first should buy a backup disk and rescue all data before attempting any repairs.

Comment: I don't think buying a new external drive is going to give you any more reliability that just copying what you can from your current external drive to the main internal SSD (assuming you have enough space). You can use the Ubuntu/GNOME "Disks" utility to make a disk image.